Springboot parameter becomes null
I was trying a code which was a bit more complex and was testing things when everything I put into spring boot came out as null in the other end
Therefore I made the program simpler until I thought I knew it should work, but it still didn't.
I am using springboot severeal places in my program, and it works there. Why doesn't it work here?
@PostMapping("/Test")
public void Test(String number)
{
  System.out.println("Number " + number);
}

$.post("/Test", "1")

This is what my console prints:
Number null


You're sending the 1 value as the body of the request, not as the named number parameter. I'm not familiar with Springboot, but I'm assuming the model binder doesn't work like that

For Post you have to use @RequestBody
try
@PostMapping("/Test")
public void Test( @RequestBody String number)
{
  System.out.println("Number " + number);
}


Assuming this will be your java code.
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/Test")
    public void test(@RequestBody String number) {
        System.out.println("Number " + number);
    }
}

you need to pass it like below code.
// Make a POST request using jQuery's $.post method
$.post('/Test', { number: '123' })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log('Success:', data); // Handle the success response
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('Error:', error); // Handle any errors
    });

you can use ajax also.
// Make an AJAX POST request using jQuery
$.ajax({
    url: '/Test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { number: '123' }, // Pass the 'number' parameter
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success:', data); // Handle the success response
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('Error:', error); // Handle any errors
    }
});

